# getting wrong values when javascript data tags used to manipulate dom values on AJAX success

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, jquery, custom-data-attribute

I am setting up a cart that has many `items` and a `subtotal`. When somebody clicks `remove` the item is destroyed successfully and the item successfully hidden from the view using jquery. The problem is my calculation for the subtotal in javascript is giving me crazy numbers. I calculate the subtotal using data tags to hold values and then reseting the subtotal data tag to its new value (so new removals have the correct calculations).

### html

```
<div style="padding-top:5px;" class="container backdrop add-top">
    <div class="row itemrow">
    <div class="six offset-by-one columns">Pool Noodles</div>
    <div class="three columns">
      <ul class="unstyled cartqty">
        <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/line_items/61" class="remove-bottom" data-remote="true" id="edit_line_item_61" method="post">
                 <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
                     <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" />
                     <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />
                     <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="eQhVhHqr2ZsLR1chbyngY0XRB/S40ckR4luq37qvvkc=" /></div>
        <li class="magna remove-bottom">
                  <input class="small-input" id="line_item_quantity" name="line_item[quantity]" type="number" value="1" />
          <input class="button-to-link outerspace remove-bottom" name="commit" type="submit" value="update" /></li>
</form>     <li class="magna">
                   <a href="/line_items/61" class="destroyer button-to-link" data-method="delete" data-price="10.0" data-remote="true"  rel="nofollow">remove</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
        <div class="two columns">each @$10.00</div>
    <div class="two columns">= $10.00</div>
</div>
    <div class="row itemrow">
                  <br/>
        <div class="six offset-by-one columns">Javascript for Dummies</div>
            <div class="three columns">
        <ul class="unstyled cartqty">
            <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/line_items/59" class="remove-bottom" data-remote="true" id="edit_line_item_59" method="post">
<div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
                        <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="_method" type="hidden" value="put" />
                        <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="eQhVhHqr2ZsLR1chbyngY0XRB/S40ckR4luq37qvvkc=" /></div>
              <li class="magna remove-bottom"><input class="small-input" id="line_item_quantity" name="line_item[quantity]" type="number" value="5" />
            <input class="button-to-link outerspace remove-bottom" name="commit" type="submit" value="update" /></li>
</form>       <li class="magna"><a href="/line_items/59" class="destroyer button-to-link" data-method="delete" data-price="50.0" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow">remove</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="two columns">each @$10.00</div>
<div class="two columns">= $50.00</div>
</div>
<div class="row checks">
    <br/>
        <div class="three offset-by-eleven columns">
            <span class="pull-right">
    Subtotal:&nbsp; <span id="subtotal" data-sub="60.0">$60.00</span>
                    </span>
        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

### Javascript

```
jQuery(function() {
    return $("a[data-remote]").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
        e.preventDefault();
        newVal = (Number($("#subtotal").data('sub')) - Number($(this).data('price'))).toFixed(2);
        console.log("newval="+newVal);
        $("#subtotal").html("$" + newVal);
        $("#subtotal").attr('data-sub', newVal);
        return $(this).closest('.itemrow').hide();
    });
});
```

subtotal = 60.

When I delete the first object (pool noodles, full price =10.00)

Then subtotal goes to 50 (Correct) [all data attributes are as expected]

When I delete the second object (javascript for dummies, full price =50.00)

Then subtotal goes to 10 (incorrect, it should be 0) [data-sub = "10"]

Why is this happening? where is 10 coming from? Any insight is appreciated.

Is there a better way to do this using the jquery .each() method?

### EDIT

I added console.log to the js in an attempt to debug. I got the following in the console:

```
newval=50.00
newval=50.00
newval=10.00
newval=10.00
newval=10.00
```

Seems weird, I'm using RoR. I have a destroy action for LineItems which responds with format.js corresponding to destroy.js.erb (where this posted js lives):

```
def destroy
    @line_item = LineItem.find(params[:id])
    @line_item.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to current_cart_url }
            format.js
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

So, if I read right you are adding and subtracting to a total each time something is removed?
I find it's always better to recount everything, it's so much easier to maintain than a half dozen edit operations(add,delete,number change, qty change is a curve ball).

Here is a function that can add up all input's that match a selector(Your selector would obviously be different).

```
function add(){
    var total = 0;
    $('input').each(function(i,domEl){
            var val = $(domEl).val();
            if(!isNaN(val)){
                total += parseFloat(val);
            }
    });
    return total;
}
```

Comment: this seems like a good .each() solution, is data attributes not best practice? Does smell a little bad.

Comment: I don't know what is storing the item data. You can use edit this function to loop through any DOM elements and read whatever property you happen to be storing them in. I like to keep subtotals in arrays myself and loop the array. But it all depends on how you've set it up.

Answer (score 1):

Quick fix is to change this:

$("#subtotal").attr('data-sub', newVal);

To this:

$("#subtotal").data('sub', newVal);

Comment: `newval=50.00
newval=0.00
newval=-50.00
newval=-100.00
newval=-150.00`

Comment: You only have two items to delete in your example, how are you getting 5 newval console outputs?  I used your code posted above, changed that one line and ran the jquery method twice for the two added items and I got 60 went to 50 and then 50 went to 0 on remove.

Comment: was it on an ajax:success event?

Comment: I found a solution below which incorporates your answer slightly

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I was looking for. Used .each() and a data-attribute for each line-item link. Data-attribute of clicked link are set to 0 on successful ajax call. Line-items are iterated through adding each data-price together and replacing subtotal with the sum.

```
function addItems(){
  var subtotal = 0;
  $('.destroyer').each(function(index){
  var val = $(this).data('price');
  if(!isNaN(val)){
      subtotal += parseFloat(val);
    }
  });
  return total;
}
jQuery(function() {
    return $("a[data-remote]").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).data('price', 0);
        $(this).closest('.itemrow').hide();
        total = addItems();
        return $("#subtotal").html("$" + Number(total).toFixed(2));
    });
});
```